# I'm using Nuxt 3 with Electron JS but why does building an app result in a white screen on startup?

Tags: electron, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Good day everyone,

I'm trying to put out a build from my ElectronJS/Nuxt 3 app. I only see a white screen. I've tried the hashmode option mentioned around SO but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong such that it still doesn't work? I'm pasting my code below to see if anyone can help steer me in the right direction. I've analyzed the files and the problem is in vue-router, specifically how it puts the path for resource files as `file:///` instead of the absolute path.

Here is my nuxt.config.ts:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false,
  router: {
    options: {
      hashMode: true
    }
  },
  app: {
    baseURL: './',
  },
  modules: ['nuxt-primevue', 'nuxt-electron'],
  css: ['~/assets/theme.css', '~/assets/styles.css'],
  electron: {
    build: [
      {
        // Main-Process entry file of the Electron App.
        entry: 'electron/main.ts',
      },
      {
        entry: 'electron/preload.ts',
        onstart(options) {
          // Notify the Renderer-Process to reload the page when the Preload-Scripts build is complete, 
          // instead of restarting the entire Electron App.
          options.reload()
        },
      },
    ],
    renderer: {},
  }
})
```

I would appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: Could you share a link to a self-contained app that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Nuxt 3.8, try downgrading to Nuxt 3.7.